# Show the number of the post

Tags: categories, theme-development, loop, pagination, count

I'd like to show the Number of the post near the post in a category. It's simpler to explain with a drawing than with words:
[image: example]

My first solution was a simple counter inside the loop, but it doesn't work with pagination and puts the number 1 at the more recent post and not at the oldest.

Is something like this possible? How? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a formula to calculate the position from current page and posts per page.

Comment: How I can get the data needed for the calculation?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! Could you include your code and what you already tried, the category object already contains a property that has the count of posts attached to it, it's `count`

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! This is my code now and apparently it's working, but maybe I'm missing something: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/odesazutev.php